# Jasmine - How To Mock Global Variables & Functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I have a script I would like to test that includes global variables with some of them being initialized with functions calls.  For example

```
var g_count = 0;
var g_util = addLibrary( "util.lib" );
```

I would like to mock both `g_count` and `g_util`

If I have a function call within my testing function I can easily mock it with `addLibrary = jasmine.createSpy();` but once it is in global scope, the mock fails and I get an error message

> Reference Error: addLibrary is not defined.

**Edit:** I figured out how to mock the variable.  I added it to a global property,

```
var globals = {
    g_count : null
}
```

Exported it

```
module.exports = {
    globals: globals
}
```

Then spied on it

```
spyOnProperty(util.globals, 'g_count').and.returnValue(5);
```

I still can't figure out the `addLibrary` function

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error for the `addLibrary`.  Since it is used to initialize a global variable it was being called when I required the script.  Adding `addLibrary = jasmine.createSpy();` above the `require(...)` fixed it.